# Subscribe emits one item at the time instead of a list in Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am currently struggling to figure out a behaviour in Rxjs in an Angular 4 application.

My code is:

```
this.server.get("incidents") //http get resource
.flatMap((res) => res.value) //the incident array is in a property called value of the json returned
.map((incident) => new Incident(incident)) // conversion from json to typed class
.subscribe(i => {this.ng2TableData.push(i);}) //subscribe
```

At the last line, I expect the subscribe method to provide me the whole list at once, instead it seems the obsevable is returning one `Incident` at the time and the subscribe function is called N times, therefore forcing me to have the `push` method, instead of building the `ng2TableData` in one go.

How do I subscribe to the whole list, rather than one item at the time?

Comment: Don't use `flatMap` then, since `flatMap` will flatten your array value into an observable stream of values.

Comment: why you even use flatMap in the first place?

Comment: But if I use map instead of flatmap, in the second map I am getting as the input the full array rather than the individual incident. What would be the correct way to do this with map instead of flatmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flatMap` will flatten your array into an observable stream of values. You just want to use `map`. You can use `map` again, to make each object in your array as instance of your class like so:

```ts
this.server.get("incidents")
  .map(res => res.value.map(incident => new Incident(incident)))
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data)) // data is an array!
```

Now you get your array inside subscribe instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that's it! It is obvious once you wrote it, but in my head the solution was a concatenation of rxjs methods, rather than a nested map method